# Colour not filling whole of object

Tags: materials, sculpting

When I add a material to this object with a principled bdsf and just a base colour it appears patchy. I have used the sculpting brush on the object and it seems like the colour is only effecting these parts that I have sculpted. Lighting does change it a bit but not entirely.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Faceorientation

Press Alt+V and select face orientation, the whole object should  be blue, means the faces are oriented the right way. Blue = outside, Red = inside.

2. Alternative model

Maybe it would be better to use a single vertex with some extrusions to shape branches, with modifiers shown in image bellow. To make parts thinner select the vertex and press ctrl+a

Something like this:

[image]

To get a more organic look add a lattice object. Select lattice and change the resolution.

[image]

Then add a lattice modifier to the tree-like-object. Note: Object has to be the lattice you created. After that, move vertices from the lattice in editmode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I got an error report message saying: Cannot rip selected faces. The original object started as a cube that I merged at the centre and then made the formation of the tree and trunks and then used the skin modifier and then used ctrl + a to shape it. Then I used dynamic topology at a constant detail to sculpt the tree giving it more detail. Could that be why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Before sculpting, the modifiers have to be applied. Couldn't reproduce the error message. If this was the case, please let us know.

Comment: All the modifiers were applied. I've resorted to just going over the parts that were grey with the sculpt brush. Not perfect but it's less noticeable. Thanks for taking the time to help me. Edit: Not sure if it's relevant but if I switch to Viewport Shading it's not patchy at all and is fully coloured. It's only when I render the image that I get the problem.